# R programming. How to open files by taking data from user?

Tags: r, csv

I have a folder containing 10 files namely 1.csv,2.csv ....  10.csv

I have to take a number from the user from 1 to 10 and open the corresponding file.
Here's my code:
I have saved the number from user in x.
Now,

```
y<-as.character(x)
y<-paste(y,csv,sep=".")
read.csv("y")
```

But this isnt working. Why? Please help

Comment: Don't quote your variable names. They need to be evaluated and quoting them makes them character constants.

Comment: Also you don't have to convert x to character as paste will do it anyways and `csv` should be `"csv"`: `y <- paste(x, "csv", sep = ".")`

Answer (score 2):

You meant to do `read.csv(y)` instead of `read.csv("y")`.